# SVG <defs> generates blank space

Tags: html, svg

I'm using SVG in my project, now I have to create a SVG element inside a web page with only `<defs>`.
Later in the page I've to use many times the objects defined earlier.
The problem lies in the object with the definitions, infact it creates a blank space in the page.
Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
            <defs>
                <polygon id="star" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
            </defs>
        </svg>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190">
            <use x=0 y=0 xlink:href="#star">
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have the problem with both Firefox and Chrome. I don't care about IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add zero dimensions to the defining `<svg>` tag:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <polygon id="star" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

As you set neither viewport nor dimensions, I guess, the browser tried to infer values here and thus resulting in a "default size" for the SVG, thus rendering the empty space.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, set `display: none` to the `<svg>` with the `<defs>` element:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="display: none;">
        <defs>
            <polygon id="star" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: The space is reduced but it isn't vanished. Try to move the definition after the use, you'll see the use move up and the blank space move down.

Comment: @MaxMarkson In my FF and Chrome the `<defs>`-SVG vanished completely. Are you sure, there are not some paddings or margins applied somewhere?

Comment: Check this images:
http://imageshack.us/a/img819/2999/defsafter.png
http://imageshack.us/a/img826/1323/defsbefore.png

Comment: @MaxMarkson Ok different solution: Try applying `style="display: none"` to the defs-svg. This does not conflict with the use and the element is definitely not shown.

Comment: Be carefull, adding `display: none` to the svg element will cause any `<pattern>` element in its defs to not render at all

Comment: **No dice**. `display:none;` causes any defs like clipPath to not render. (when called i.e: using `clip-path: url("#clipPath1");`)

Answer (score 20):

The two reasons why this is happening is:

- lack of dimensions
- `<svg>` are rendered as `display:inline`

Adding dimensions to the `<svg>` tag will initially hide most of the space taken but a small portion will remain.

Setting `display:none` will hide any patterns / gradients / etc referenced in other `<svg>` elements and so is not appropriate.

To hide it completely, set the `<svg>` tag as `display:block`. It will then respect the zero-length dimensions given earlier.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="display: block;">
    <defs>
        <polygon id="star" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: This only worked after also setting `width="0"` and `height="0"` in combination with either `display: block` or `position: absolute`.

Comment: This is definitely not intuitive

Answer (score 0):

use vw vw for both width and height .

```
<svg
 width="20vw"
 height="10vw"
 viewBox="0 0 212 73"
 fill="none"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```